# Callback method in child component updating parent state but not props it's passed

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to create a nested checkbox form whereby if parent filter (i.e Tropical) is checked, the children nested underneath automatically gets checked. When a user clicks submit, I'm able to grab all the selected checkbox values. There's a parent filter component, which is a simple form that has all the updated states for selected checkboxes.

```
class ParentFilters extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            selectedFruit: [],
        selectedSport: []
      };
            this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
      this.updateFruitSelection = this.updateFruitSelection.bind(this);
    }

        handleFormSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
      const formPayload = {
        Fruit: this.state.selectedFruit,
        Sport: this.state.selectedSport
      };
            console.log('Send this in a POST request:', formPayload);
    }

    updateFruitSelection(newSelectionArray){
            this.setState({ selectedFruit: newSelectionArray });
        }

    render(){
        return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                <div className="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div className= "panel panel-default">

              <FilterByFruit
              updateFruitSelection = {this.updateFruitSelection}
              selectedOptions={this.state.selectedFruit} />

              <input type="submit" className="submitButton btn btn-default"         value="Submit"/>
            </div>
          </div>
         </form>
       );
    }
  }
```

In there, I pass in 2 props, selectedFruits and a callback function to update selectedFruits state in the parentFilter.

The FilterByFruit child component looks like this:

```
class FilterByFruit extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.checkOrUncheckAllSuboptions = this.checkOrUncheckAllSuboptions.bind(this);
        this.handleFruitSelection = this.handleFruitSelection.bind(this);
    }

    checkOrUncheckAllSuboptions(e) {
        var checkboxes = $('#tropicalFruitSuboptions input')
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            const newSelection = checkboxes[i].value;
            this.handleFruitSelection(newSelection);
        }
    }

    handleFruitSelection(e) {
        var newSelection
        if (e.target !== undefined) {
            newSelection = e.target.value;
        } else {
            newSelection = e;
        }
        let newSelectionArray;
        if (this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf(newSelection) > -1) {
            newSelectionArray = this.props.selectedOptions.filter(s => s !== newSelection)
        } else {
            newSelectionArray = [...this.props.selectedOptions, newSelection];
        }
        this.props.updateFruitSelection(newSelectionArray);
    }
render() {
        return (
  <div className="panel-heading">
    <label className="form-label panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#fruits">Fruits</a>
    </label>

  <div id="fruits" className="checkbox-group panel-collapse collapse">
    <div className="list-group-item">

      <label key="Tropical" className="form-label capitalize">
        <input
        className="form-checkbox"
        onChange={this.checkOrUncheckAllSuboptions}
        value="Tropical"
        checked={this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf("Tropical") > -1}
        type={'checkbox'} />
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tropicalFruitSuboptions"> Tropical</a>
      </label>

        <div id="tropicalFruitSuboptions" className="checkbox-group panel-collapse collapse indentOption">
          <label key="Pineapple" className="form-label capitalize">
            <input
              className="form-checkbox"
              onChange={this.handleFruitSelection}
              value="Pineapple"
              checked={this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf("Pineapple") > -1}
              type={'checkbox'} /> Pineapple
          </label>

          <label key="Guava" className="form-label capitalize">
            <input
              className="form-checkbox"
              onChange={this.handleFruitSelection}
              value="Guava"
              checked={this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf("Guava") > -1}
              type={'checkbox'} /> Guava
          </label>
        </div>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    );
   }
 }
```

Here's a demo of what I have so far:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ppdegw

If I select each of the children filter (Pineapple, Guava), it gets logged into selectedFruits correctly. However, when I select the parent filter (Tropical), only the last Guava checkbox gets ticked off. It seems that even though I can correctly use the callback prop function in my FilterByFruit component to my parent Filter component and subsequently update the state of selectedFruit, it doesn't update the `selectedOptions={this.state.selectedFruit} />` prop that is passed to FilterByFruit. In addition, I would rather not use jQuery to select and auto-check the nested checkboxes, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: i have inspected your code and there is wrong about how you handle the changing of selection. you have this `const newSelection = checkboxes[i].value;
    this.handleFruitSelection(newSelection);` inside the loop, which means it will be called once on each item on the array. and the last value it will call will be the one saved on the state. you can solve this by changing this logic.